# sentence correction with either .... or

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

> Either his parents or Pheroze is going to come today.

The author of the book suggests as :

> Either Pheroze  or his parents are going to come today.  = OK

---

We know with ( either \ or and neither\ nor ) the last verb agrees with the closer noun to ( or \ nor)
So, it is correct on its original pattern.
Pheroze = singular and using ( is ) = correct
My question " Why to move the singular noun ( Pheroze) to be directly after either "
Is this a technique or a new technique?

Comment: My instinct as a native speaker is that "his parents... is" sounds very awkward with only two words in between.

Comment: This is entirely a stylistic choice, but the "normal" choice is to identify the subject *first* if it's coupled within a compound noun phrase with something *connected* to the subject, and therefore requiring a possessive "forward reference" (such as the word ***his*** here). But if a writer ***did*** make the less common sequence choice, he'd be very likely to emphasise the construction with a reflexive pronoun: *Either his parents or Pheroze **himself** is going to come today*. And there's always scope for disagreement regarding whether that should be ***is*** or ***are** going to come.*

Answer (score 1):

I got it  Blue Grammar book suggests the following rule :

Rule 5

**When a singular and plural subject are connected by either/or or neither/nor, put the plural subject last and use a plural verb.
Example: Neither Jenny nor the others are available**